# Should tests be in the same Ruby file or in separated Ruby files?

Tags: ruby, selenium, functional-testing

While using Selenium and Ruby to do some functional tests, I am worried with the performance. So is it better to add all test methods in the same Ruby file, or I should put each one in separated code files?

Below a sample with all tests in the same file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class Tests < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def setup
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        @base_url = "http://mysite"
        @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
        @verification_errors = []
        @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new :timeout => 10
    end


    def teardown
        @driver.quit
        assert_equal [], @verification_errors
    end

    def element_present?(how, what)
        @driver.find_element(how, what)
        true
        rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
        false
    end

    def verify(&blk)
        yield
        rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
        @verification_errors << ex
    end

    def test_1

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # a huge test here

    end

    def test_2

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # a huge test here

    end

    def test_3

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # a huge test here

    end

    def test_4

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # a huge test here

    end

    def test_5

        @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
        # a huge test here

    end
end
```

Comment: What aspect of performance are you worried about, and why?

Comment: the speed when running one test just after another. To put all test methods in the same file would be better for processing?

Answer (score 4):

The number of files comprising your tests will be mostly irrelevant - The time spent running the tests themselves will be much greater than the time spent loading and compiling the files.

Instead try to keep your test code manageable - group related tests together, and try to keep the files withion the very rough ballpark of 50-500 lines.

Comment: This. Code parsing and test method invokation will only take up an unnoticeable fraction of the time it takes to run the tests...